# Searching for words in MS Word Document from Delphi with RegEx and import to Delphi app

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I am working with our lab report system and want to automate some of the tasks. The system we use is not intuitive and uses word documents to enter data.  There are several paragraphs with headings (protected headings).

I want to copy a phrase in one of the paragraphs and paste it into another paragraph using a Delphi app

```
GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
```

How can I use a RegEx for that. The good thing is the searchable phrases I want to copy are in uppercase while everything else is sentence case. example:

3rd paragraph heading:---> Receiver Notes <---- this is not editable in the document (protected)

1. the specimen is received in CONTAINER OF FORMALIN at this workstation
2. the specimen is received FRESH WITH NO FIXATIVE at this workstation

my result has to be something like:

4th paragraph heading --->Methods of Receiving <------ protected again

1. CONTAINER OF FORMALIN   <----- here is where I want to paste from the first match
2. FRESH WITH NO FIXATIVE   <----- and here the second match … etc

So my feeling is to have a delphi code to search between paragraph heading "Receiver Note" and "Methods of Receiving" for those in upper case and list them in the next paragraph.

I use delphi xe3 and I know how to use regex with other files but not in word using delphi. Any input, code snippets, examples, etc would be much appreciated!

Comment: You would be better off using Word Automation instead of trying to do this with a regex (Word documents are encoded with formatting info, so you'd have to extract the text first anyway). With Word automation, you could grab the entire paragraph (or any group of paragraphs) and access the individual lines easily, using the Word VBA Object Model, which is pretty well documented.

Comment: You'vegot good point there. I have very limited experience with word automation. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Here's an off-site list of examples [one](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoWord.htm#HowDoI). See `TWordApplication` and `TWordDocument` components on the `Servers` tab in the component palette. Those should get you started, and once you have an idea what to ask here, there are people who are pretty knowledgeable about Office automation and Delphi that answer questions here. (I would add the generic `delphi` tag to your questions, and omit the `delphi-xe3` unless your question is version-specific. Most things that aren't FireMonkey or XPlatform related are generic.)

Comment: (continued) Posting a Word automation answer to this question would be inappropriate, as your question isn't about Word automation. Any automation-related answer would be "not an answer", as it doesn't address your posted question. (You could post a different question, though; whether to leave this one or not is up to you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally got this to work and I am posting the code if incase someone needs this. I had to copy the document to my delphi Memo and work it there with regex and then paste it back where I want.  Although the process may seem cumbersome, it executes very fast. The word documents I work with are usually one or two pages anyways.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DXRANGE, DXWORD: OleVariant;
  n : Integer;
  regexpr: TRegEx;
  Match: TMatch;
begin
  try
    DXWORD := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');

    DXRANGE := DXWORD.Documents.Item(1)
      .Range(DXWORD.Documents.Item(1).Range.Start, DXWORD.Documents.Item(1)
      .Range.End);
    DXRANGE.Copy;
    Memo1.Clear;
    Memo1.PasteFromClipBoard;
    regexpr := TRegEx.Create('\b[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b');
    Match := regexpr.Match(Memo1.Text);
    n := 1;
    Memo2.Clear;
    while Match.Success do
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(n) + Match.Value);
      Memo2.Lines.Add('');
      Match := Match.NextMatch;
      n := n + 1;
    end;
    Memo2.SelectAll;
    Memo2.CopyToClipboard;
    DXWORD.Selection.PasteSpecial(wdPasteRTF)
  except
    on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule when working with Word (or any office app) and ActiveX Delphi component, is to use the amazing macro recorder to see how it would do it.

eg.

- Open your word document
- Select [Record Macro] from the tools menu
- Do your search
- Copy it to the clipboard
- Replace your code
- Do Whatever else you need to do.
- Stop Macro

Now open up the macro VBA organiser and look at the code VBA has generated for what you did.  This will give you a very good idea of the functions you need to get your delphi code to call.

Comment: Yes, I usually do that after I learned  that few weeks ago. I tried to record how word does it by recording macro, using the wild type enabled. But the macro recorded was not helpful.Thanks for your input!